# Msg type for publishing JointCommands?

Tags: ros, ros2, jointstate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a commonly used msg type for sending JointCommands across topics?

It has been bugging me for a while that I can't seem to find something like [sensor_msgs/msg/JointState.msg](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/sensor_msgs/msg/JointState.msg), but for commanding positions for multiple joints to move immediately.

I want to avoid writing a custom message if possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387380/msg-type-for-publishing-jointcommands?/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2021-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any standardised messages for this specifically.

`JointState` is indeed for reporting state. Not for commanding it.

For trajectory(-like) interfaces, we have `JointTrajectory` (and the related `FollowJointTrajectory` action).

I've seen authors accept `JointTrajectoryPoint`, but the disadvantage of that message is that it does not contain a `names` field (or something similar), which obviously means you have no way of checking any semantics of the incoming data.

Other nodes accept `Float64MultiArray`, but that's obviously less than ideal as well as it has almost no semantics whatsoever (except perhaps "here is a bunch of float numbers in a list). `ros_control` is a good example of a context where that message is used, but see [ros2_controllers#157](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/issues/157) where they recognise they need something else (similar to your question really).

Yet another alternative: accept `JointTrajectory` instances, but limit them to a maximum length of two (or one). While somewhat strange, this solves the problem of not having access to the targetted joint names, while also using something which has been traditionally used for commanding new state. It's also a nice intermediary between trajectory-based control interfaces and position-streaming ones (with trajectory-replacement allowing for even more gradual changing between the two).

On the Cartesian side, I've seen `geometry_msgs/Pose` (or `PoseStamped` of course) and even plain `Point` being used. It's slightly easier here, as the dimensionality of the message corresponds directly to the number of degrees of freedom of the mechanism being controlled (we only have 3 dimensions of space ..), so there is less need for a `names` field to help interprete the data.

The [FZI: Cartesian Interface in ROS](https://fzi-robot-interface-proposal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) project took that a bit further and designed a complete set of messages for Cartesian (position/velocity/etc) control of ROS robots, which resulted in [cartesian_control_msgs](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_cartesian_control_msgs). That's not in ROS 2 right now though (and doesn't directly address your need).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-09-27**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for your insight on this topic.

I feel that it would have been more natural if the `joint_names[]` field of `JointTrajectory.msg` was inside `JointTrajectoryPoint.msg`, but I think that design decision comes from trying to avoid having the `joint_names` repeated for every point in time.

Nonetheless, I think it makes sense to have a separate data type such as `JointCommand.msg`:

```
string[] names
float64[] positions
float64[] velocities
float64[] accelerations
float64[] effort
```

or even separate msgs for `JointPositionCommand.msg` `JointVelocityCommand.msg` `JointAccelerationCommand.msg` and `JointEffortCommand.msg` .

I also think that such msgs should be part of `std_msgs`, rather than `control_msgs` if possible.
Perhaps this should be moved to a Discourse discussion rather than a Q&A, what do you think?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-27**:
You can always post a topic on Discourse.

re: in `std_msgs`: please refer to the linked `ros2_control` issue. `std_msgs` is deprecated. I would be very much surprised if any more additions to it would be accepted.

I also don't agree with your assertion that "it should be in std_msgs". From a semantics point-of-view, `control_msgs` seems much more appropriate.

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-09-27**:
Oops, I meant `common_interfaces`, not `std_msgs`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-27**:
I believe that wouldn't change my response. This is clearly a message which is intended to be used in situations where you want to *control* some mechanism / robot. What is your motivation for wanting to put it in `common_interfaces`?

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-09-27**:
For a motor that has a position controller onboard, there is no need to use the `ros-control` package. My thought process is "Well, I'm not using ros-control, why should I use msgs from ros-control?".

My understanding of `control_msgs` is that it contains msgs used when communicating to the `ros2_control` package. That's the part where I may be wrong, perhaps control_msgs isn't tied to `ros-control` but is intended to be more general?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-28**:
`control_msgs` is not tied to `ros_control` at all. It's a stand-alone message package with quite some usage outside `ros_control`.

And the context you describe would actually fit very well with `ros_control`. The fact your motor "has a position controller board" does not really change anything. `ros_control` is first and foremost a *resource management framework*.

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-09-30**:\

> `control_msgs` is not tied to `ros_control` at all

Great!

> `ros_control` is first and foremost a resource management framework.

I thought `ros_control` was specifically for performing control calculations, good to clarify that that's not the case.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-01**:
You won't find many people describing `ros_control` the way I did/do. But once you get more familiar with it, I believe my description starts to make more sense.